# How to use working-directory in GitHub actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to set-up and run a GitHub action in a nested folder of the repo.

I thought I could use [`working-directory`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-set-the-default-shell-and-working-directory), but if I write this:

```yaml
jobs:
  test-working-directory:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Test
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: my_folder
    steps:
      - run: echo test
```

I get an error:

```
Run echo test
echo test
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/home/runner/work/my_repo/my_repo/my_folder'. No such file or directory
```

I notice `my_repo` appears twice in the path of the error.

[Here is the run on my repo](https://github.com/ValentinVignal/novade_flutter_packages/runs/6644045690?check_suite_focus=true), where:

- `my_repo = novade_flutter_packages`
- `my_folder = packages`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't check out the repository on the second job.

Each job runs on a different instance, so you have to checkout it separately for each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to checkout the repository on the runner in order to use files in the repository.

For example, my repository has a `/requirements.txt` file which I want to `pip install -r requirements.txt` from, but I have to checkout my repository to ensure the file exists on the runner first.

```
jobs:
  my-job:
    name: my job
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4.7.0
        with:
          python-version: 3.11
      # without this step, the pip install step will fail
      - name: Checkout the repo 
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Python requirements
        run: |
          pip install -r requirements.txt
```